# Collections sort on a copy of a Arraylist (to keep the orginal order)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

If i have an arraylist, and i want both a sorted and unsorted version of it, how can i achive it.

tried with Collections

```
ArrayList<Integer> someNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

if i then make a new arraylist = someNumbers and sort it. The orginal one gets sorted too ?

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = someNumbers;
Collections.sort(sortedNumbers);
```

both list gets sorted.

How can i simply achive what im trying to do ? ( get a sorted copy, and keep the orginal in its orginal ordering )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do `ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = someNumbers;`, you are not creating a new list to sort. You are basically assigning the variable `sortedNumbers` to the exact same list that `someNumbers` is assigned to.

To fix it, you can create a new list from your other list. Like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(someNumbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a copy of the list and then sort it, e.g.

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(someNumbers);
Collections.sort(sortedNumbers);
```

This uses [`ArrayList(java.util.Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) constructor

Comment: My concern here is to name it `sorted` while it's not yet.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why both lists get sorted is because even you first create a `new ArrayList()`, you then override this instance with a reference to `someNumbers`. Therefore when you sort `sortedNumbers` you actually sort the original list `someNumbers`.

There are several ways you can achieve your goal:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
sortedNumbers.addAll(someNumbers);
```

Or you can achieve the same in one step by using the copy constructor:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(someNumbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the array and sort the copy:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(someNumbers);
Collections.sort(sortedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy the ArrayList first to have two versions. Then you can sort one of the two ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<Integer> someNumbers = ...
ArrayList<Integer> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>(someNumbers);
Collections.sort(sortedNumbers);
```